# Changing the frameset row value in IE,Chrome is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am changing the frameset with this line

```
parent.document.getElementById('frameSetId').rows = "'0%','100%','0%'";
```

this is the frameset i am changing

```
<frameset id="frameSetId" name="frameSetId" rows="100%,0%,0%" framespacing="0" border = "0" frameborder="0">

<frame name="top1" src="show_trade_diary.php" scrolling="no" target="_self">
<frame name="bottom1" src="trading_diary.php" scrolling="no" style="border-style: " >
<frame name="bottom2" src="trading_diary_iecd.php" scrolling="no" style="border-style: " >
```

Javascript code is working fine in Firefox . It doesnt work in IE,Chrome. Is there something diferent that needs to be done in IE and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
parent.document.getElementById('frameSetId').rows = "0,*,0";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
parent.document.getElementById('frameSetId').setAttribute("rows","0%,100%,0%");
```

Is your HTML well formed? There are no closing tags and your style attributes are invalid...